# Trying to render a bunch of items per second from a WS to FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

The problem is that is not even possible with a bunch of messages per second, but even with a slower channel (1 message per second) it starts to lag at the 5th message, i was planning on make it work first and then optimize, but i could do even that.

my questions are, is it limitation of FlatList?, am i not using state/context correctly?, should i use redux?

My code looks something like this.

WebSocket:

```
const tmi = require("tmi.js");

export const tmiClient = () => {
  const client = new tmi.Client({
    channels: ["xqc"],
  });

  client.connect();
  return client;
};
```

Context Provider:

```
export const MessagesContext = createContext();

export const MessagesContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([
    {
      id: "12345",
      username: "Subject",
      message: "Test",
    },
  ]);
  const [tmi, setTmi] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTmi(tmiClient());
  }, []);

  tmi &&
    tmi.on("message", (channel, tags, message, self) => {
      const msg = {
        id: tags.id,
        username: tags["display-name"],
        message,
      };
      add(msg);
    });

  const add = (msg) => {
    setMessages([...messages, msg]);
  };

  return (
    <MessagesContext.Provider
      value={{
        messages,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </MessagesContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

FlatList Component:

```
const Item = ({ value }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{value.message}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export const ChatList = () => {
  const { messages } = useContext(MessagesContext);
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return <Item value={item} />;
  };
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={messages}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

App.js:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <MessagesContextProvider>
      <ChatList />
    </MessagesContextProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `Context` provider to look like this, and now works as intended

```
export const MessagesContext = createContext();

export const MessagesContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([
    {
      id: "12345",
      username: "Subject",
      message: "Test",
    },
  ]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const tmi = tmiClient();
    tmi.on("message", (channel, tags, message, self) => {
      const msg = {
        id: tags.id,
        username: tags["display-name"],
        message,
        color: tags.color,
      };
      setMessages((m) => [...m, msg]);
    });

    tmi.disconnect();
  }, []);

  return (
    <MessagesContext.Provider
      value={{
        messages,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </MessagesContext.Provider>
  );
};
```